# yocto build (zeus) fails to present a login screen through hdmi

Tags: hdmi, boot-issues, yocto

I am attempting to build an rpi-sdimg using yocto.
I have attempted to bitbake "rpi-basic-image-raspberrypi3" and "rpi-hwup-image-raspberrypi3".

My "conf/local.conf" looks like :

```
MACHINE ??= "raspberrypi3"
DISTRO ?= "poky"
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += " dev-pkgs tools-sdk tools-debug   "
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-system-native = " sdl"
CONF_VERSION = "1"
GPU_MEM = "64"
PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j 8"
INSTALL_append = " rpi-config "
```

and in the boot partition of the sdcard "config.txt" :

```
hdmi_safe=1
gpu_mem=64
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```

and cmdline.txt :

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
```

these are the defaults (I did enable hdmi_safe while googling for issues), yet when I try to boot the raspberry pi 3b+ by hooking it up to my TV, I get to see the Rainbow splash, then some boot messages but eventually the TV screen goes blank and I am not presented with a login prompt, not even after 2-3 minutes (I assume that's already excessive).

So either there is something wrong with the pi or there is something missing from the configuration.

I also connected a serial (UART) in GPIO 14 and 15 just in case the system presented the login prompt through there, but this is not the case. I setup the minicom port in the pc at 115200 8N1, but received nothing (yes, I know about the 2 uarts pl011 and miniuart and tried various settings with them). 
Unfortunately there is no network being brought up (no network leds flashing), so I am completely unable to communicate with the device.

So while my initial aim is to solve the hdmi issue, If you have a link to a yocto guide that you have used and successfully managed to boot, then please by all means provide that as well.

Comment: For starters, I think you should add something like `console=serial0,115200` to the kernel command line to get a prompt on the UART.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev tried, didn't work. what did "work" was to use ttyAMA0 so all kernel boot msg disappeared from HDMI, but I never saw them over UART :(